# Need to Update Rails model by ajax call with HTML5 contenteditable but instead its creating new record

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, html

I am trying to update some plots of a stroy with HTML5 contenteditable option. here is the code.

View file# where multiple plots can be modified

```
 <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
  <%= simple_format p.description %>
 </div>
```

AJAX #

```
  $(function(){
     var contents =  $("#editable").html();
    $('#editable').blur(function() {
      if (contents!=$(this).html()){
        alert('Handler for .change() called.');
        contents = $(this).html();
        autoSavePost();
      }

   })
});

function autoSavePost(){
    var data = {id: parseInt($("#plot_id").text()), tale_id: parseInt($("#tale").text()) ,description: $("#editable").html(), user_id: parseInt($("#user").text())};
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/plots",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(){
            $("#success-indicate").fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();

        }
    });
   // setTimeout(autoSavePost, 6000);
}
```

Routes file #

```
 resources :plots do
   member do
     post 'update'
   end
 end
```

Controller file#

```
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
    if @plot.update(params[:description])
      format.html { redirect_to plots_path, notice: 'Plot was successfully updated.' }
      format.json { render:@plot }
      format.js
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
      format.json { render json: @plot.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I am asking experts help. will be grateful

Comment: Now its updating after changing the URL Patteren to "plots/id" and type to "PUT"

Answer (score 0):

Changing the ajax params to following, data is updating instead of crating

```
  function autoSavePost(){
    var id =  parseInt($("#plot_id").text());
    var data = {id: parseInt($("#plot_id").text()), tale_id: parseInt($("#tale").text()) ,description: $("#editable").html(), user_id: parseInt($("#user").text())};
    console.log(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "PUT",
        url: "/plots/" + id ,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        success: function(){
            $("#success-indicate").fadeIn().delay(4000).fadeOut();

        }
    });
   // setTimeout(autoSavePost, 6000);
}
```